# Ruby Rails - Query by Date Month

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I want to select all entries in the Game table where the date column has an entry where the month is greater than 6.  The columns for the Game table are date_column, id, winning_side, status, away_score, home_score. The DB is Postgres. Something like

```
Game.where("date_part(month, date_column) > ?", 6)
```

date_part appears to be the right SQL function but this is failing.

Comment: what are the columns in your `Game` table? - and what is `date_column`?

Comment: How is it failing? What are you expecting, what are your getting? Error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes for 'month' parameter:

```
Game.where("date_part('month', date_column) > ?", 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the word month in single quotes, i.e.

```
Game.where("date_part('month', date_column) > ?", 6)
```